Lua в redis cli - посчитать размер ключей в redis
Пробую на lua посчитать размер ключей
  local cursor = "0"
  local all_keys = {}
  local memory_usage_results = {}

  repeat
      local result = redis.call('SCAN', cursor)
      cursor = result[1]
      for _, key in ipairs(result[2]) do
          table.insert(all_keys, key)
          local usage = redis.call('MEMORY', 'USAGE', key)
          table.insert(memory_usage_results, {key = key, usage = usage})
      end
  until cursor == "0"

  return memory_usage_results

Но вывод  redis-cli  --eval script.lua 
1) (empty array)
2) (empty array)

Как правильно получить массив?
да и
local memory_usage_results = {}   
          
memory_usage_results['aa'] = '33'     
                            
return  memory_usage_results


возвращает (empty array)

А команда redis-cli  --eval точно способна возвращать таблицы Lua?
